# Change in converted time using TimeZone

Tags: c#

I have problem with the date time conversion 
the code is given below

```
DateTime indianStd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "India Standard Time");
DateTime MyanmarStd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Myanmar Standard Time");
DateTime SEAsia = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "SE Asia Standard Time");
DateTime dtConvertedDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(MyanmarStd, "India Standard Time");
```

when i print these time in a lable

indianStd Shows the time 4:30:45;

Where as ConvertedDt Shows 5:30:45 Why this one hour difference
can any body tell me Reason for this

Comment: This seems to be working as it should, due to the fact that India and Myanmar have 1 hour timezone different between them.

Comment: I Just Want to convert the Myanmar Standard time to Indian Standard Time What Should I do for getting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   DateTime indianStd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "India Standard Time");

   DateTime MyanmarStd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Myanmar Standard Time");

DateTime SEAsia = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "SE Asia Standard Time");

 DateTime ConvertedDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(MyanmarStd, "Myanmar Standard Time", "India Standard Time");
```

this Will return the currect date time

Answer (score 0):

Because they are different time zones?
http://www.happyzebra.com/timezones-worldclock/India-and-Myanmar.php

Answer (score 0):

IST and Myanmar Time Difference is 1 hour.

IST is UTC + 5.30 h
Myanmar(Rangoon) is UTC + 6.30 h

To confirm this Simply Check in your computer Date and Time -> Time Zone Settings.

[image]

Comment: this means that first it convert to utc and then converted to ISD

Comment: yes. It takes UTC as base by first converting your myanmar time to UTC and then to desired timezone ie IST.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Kind` Property of the Myanmar object. Set that to Local.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public DateTime ConvertToIndianDateTime()
{

var myanMarDateTime = your myanmar date time
myanMarDateTime.Kind = DateTimeKind.Local; 
var indianTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myanMarDateTime, indianTimeZoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
}
```